# System.Device - "Assembly Not Found for framework .Net Framework 4.7.2" in VS2019 for Mac

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2019

We have a solution which builds fine using VS2019 for Windows, but when I load it into VS2019 for Mac, I get an error for the System.Device reference, with the above error.

So it appears there is something different with the VS/.Net Framework installation on the Mac.

Some research indicates I might need to install the .Net Framework Developer Pack for 4.7.2 - but this is only available for Windows platforms (i.e. the installer is a .exe). So I think this is a read herring.

Has anyone come across this before, and got a solution?

Answer (score 0):

this might be because of accidental removal of references and packages "wrongly".
Fastest solution for me was: 
Delete-clean References and packages from Projects & solution panel on left. Then while building it will show "references are missing". So now you add all the references and packages fresh.
Re-Built it, worked fine for me.